# "Has preserved" or "has been preserved"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, tenses, past-tense

Which is correct?

> - Roman temples have not preserved in their original condition
> - Roman temples have not been preserved in their original condition

Comment: You may be interested in our site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. There are multiple issues with both.

The correct formulation is

> Roman temples have not been preserved in their original condition.

The temples are inanimate, they haven't preserved anything. You need the passive voice for this, *have not **been** preserved*.

Note also the capitalization of *Roman*, the subject-verb agreement between *temples* and *have*, and *their* instead of *the*. And *to this day* sounds wrong tacked onto the end, I'm sure a grammarian could explain why.

Comment: "To this day" doesn't fit because it means that nothing has changed, while the "have not been preserved" says the exact opposite thing.

Comment: could I use up to now/until now/up to the present instead?

Comment: @jozi not really, unless you're announcing the start of a new preservation initiative.

Answer (score 2):

One sentence is active, the other passive.

'Roman temples have not preserved....' is using the verb in the active voice. It does not  make sense as it stands as 'preserve' is a transitive verb. You could say 'Roman temples have not preserved themselves well....', but even that is a bit contrived, since temples can't do the preserving.

You need to go into the passive as per your second sentence. But remember 'has' needs to be 'have' since 'temples' is plural. And I think 'the original condition' needs to be 'their original condition'.

Answer (score 0):

"Roman temples have not been preserved", since Roman temples is the subject, which is BEING preserved.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to say. The first sentence says that the Roman Temples (when they were in their original condition) have not preserved something.

The second sentence said that the temples were not preserved in their original condition. I would think you were using the second meaning, so the second sentence is correct.